# Establishing relations from a partial differential equation with two variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have those two equations below:$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}+g\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}=0\\\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial t}+H\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0\end{cases}$$And I have$$u(x, t)=u_0e^{i(k x+\omega t)},\quad h(x,t)=h_0e^{i(k x+\omega t)}.$$
I want to establish the relationship that connects the $u_0$ and $h_0$ in one expression.

I know like we have two equations with two variables but I can't figure out how to plug all this together to obtain only one expression?

Comment: Hint: find the partial derivatives and proceed from there

Comment: can you give me an exemple?

Comment: how do I find partial derivative? I have u/t +g(h/x) = 0 for the first equation. I derivate in relation to t or x?

Comment: Last hint: You have two equations with two unknowns, and you are given two functions. How can you modify the two functions so that you may solve the system?

Comment: I plug one of them into another